# angular 6 cannot display json data on html table

Tags: angular6, asp.net-core-webapi

hello i am newbie at angular 6 and webapi .net core i am developing an application taking data from webapi and displaying in html table , the web api returns data in the form of json but angular table is not displaying data , my code snippets are as follows

web api returns data as

```
[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Patient> Get()
        {
            return _patientManager.GetAllPatients();
        }
```

at the angular client side i have a service that is working as

```
 readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:3922/api';

  constructor(private httpservice: HttpClient) { }

   getPatientData(): Observable<Patient[]> {

     return this.httpservice.get<Patient[]>(this.rootURL + '/Patient');
  }
```

the component is written as

```
   export class PatientDetailListComponent implements OnInit {

  patient: Patient[];
  constructor(private service: PatientDetailService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getPatientData()
  .subscribe((data: Patient[]) => {
    this.patient = data ;
    console.log(data);
    });
   }

}
```

the html is as

```
     <table class="table table-container">
 <thead>
     <tr>

         <th>PatientCode</th>
         <th>FirstName</th>
         <th>LastName</th>
         <th>MRN</th>
         <th>DateOFBirth</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <!--<tr ngfor = "let p of service.list">-->
   <tr *ngfor ="let p of patient;">
     <td>{{p?.PatientCode}}</td>
      <td>{{p?.FirstName}}</td>
      <td>{{p?.LastName}}</td>
      <td>{{p?.MRN}}</td>
      <td>{{p?.DateOfBirth}}</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

i am getting from web api as follows

```
[{"PatientCode":"120477","FirstName":"Leonel","LastName":"Hernandez juan","MRN":"21625","DateOfBirth":"2012-03-21T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"120523","FirstName":"Traeson","LastName":"Serna","MRN":"22848","DateOfBirth":"2012-01-21T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"438264","FirstName":"Kaylee","LastName":"Leon","MRN":"LEONKAYL","DateOfBirth":"2012-01-22T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"476679","FirstName":"Bradyn","LastName":"Wade","MRN":"296500","DateOfBirth":"2012-03-11T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"458698","FirstName":"Madison a","LastName":"Petitt","MRN":"264267","DateOfBirth":"2012-05-16T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"267924","FirstName":"Madelyn","LastName":"Lencioni","MRN":"51934","DateOfBirth":"2012-02-05T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"444373","FirstName":"Emily","LastName":"Wilson","MRN":"231859","DateOfBirth":"2012-05-19T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"459560","FirstName":"Natalie","LastName":"Steinspring","MRN":"266611","DateOfBirth":"2012-05-13T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"459689","FirstName":"Maddox","LastName":"Johnson","MRN":"358859","DateOfBirth":"2012-02-24T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"306879","FirstName":"Jeremiah","LastName":"Benabe","MRN":"79178","DateOfBirth":"2012-01-21T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"388466","FirstName":"Jewellz","LastName":"Jones","MRN":"407331","DateOfBirth":"2012-06-08T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"388579","FirstName":"Trinity","LastName":"Myers","MRN":"609518","DateOfBirth":"2012-03-09T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"510217","FirstName":"Shubu ladeigh josiah","LastName":"Macthompson","MRN":"881738","DateOfBirth":"2012-06-24T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"538957","FirstName":"Ruvenia","LastName":"Sameer","MRN":"305381","DateOfBirth":"2012-02-19T00:00:00"},{"PatientCode":"554357","FirstName":"Kaleb","LastName":"Daniel","MRN":"960885","DateOfBirth":"2012-05-06T00:00:00"}]
```

but i am getting error on html view as

> compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("  
>   -->    ]*ngfor
>   ="let p of patient;">
>        {{p?.PatientCode}}
>         {{p?.FirstName}} "): ng:///AppModule/PatientDetailListComponent.html@13:7 Property binding
>   ngforOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure
>   that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are
>   listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("     -->    [ERROR ->]
>        {{p?.PatientCode}}
>         {{p?.FirstName}} "): ng:///AppModule/PatientDetailListComponent.html@13:3
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
>       at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
>   (compiler.js:20605)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate
>   (compiler.js:26171)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate
>   (compiler.js:26158)
>       at compiler.js:26101
>       at Set.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
>   (compiler.js:26101)
>       at compiler.js:26011
>       at Object.then (compiler.js:2421)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
>   (compiler.js:26010) syntaxError @ compiler.js:2430
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
>   @ compiler.js:20605
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate
>   @ compiler.js:26171
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate
>   @ compiler.js:26158 (anonymous) @ compiler.js:26101
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
>   @ compiler.js:26101 (anonymous) @ compiler.js:26011 then @
>   compiler.js:2421
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
>   @ compiler.js:26010
>   push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync
>   @ compiler.js:25970
>   push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync
>   @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143 compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ @
>   core.js:17618
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule
>   @ core.js:17801 ./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78 0 @ main.ts:12
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78 checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45 webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32 (anonymous) @ main.js:1

please help where i am doing wrong, spent whole day but found nothing TIA

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo, not *ngfor but:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of patient">
```

and also you should check if you get an object or a JSON string from server

Comment: thank you Forsaken, just correct the typo and WOALA get the result in grid, Thanks again